# LM339 window not switching

Tags: led, comparator

I made a pair of window comparators with a quad LM339, and LEDs on the outputs. The LEDs flickered near the switchover points.

So I made a test setup on a plugboard. The LEDs didn't flicker (typical!), but nevertheless I went ahead and added some positive feedback, as various websites said it should cure the oscillation. See the pic.

The result now is even worse! The pots act like dimmers, fading the LEDs on and off near the switching point.

Any suggestions please?

[image]

Comment: Please consider drawing your circuit in the site's schematic editor. To do so, [edit] your post and hit Ctrl-M.

Comment: What's the voltage out from the pots? Do you have supply bypass capacitors at the comparator supply pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I was trying to use too narrow a hysteresis band. Changing the 39K and 100K resistors to 270K and 1M made it work ok with an acceptable amount of hysteresis.
Thanks to all for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a purely resistive pull-up. Connect, for example, 4k7 Ohm between LM339 output and +5V, in parallel with 1k and LED.

The LM339 has an open collector output and when it tries to go high the LED will switch off, thus removing the pull to +5.

Comment: Hi, and thanks, but that didn't seem to make much difference. I'm currntly studying one of Texas' excellent docs, SNOA664A.PDF. I.